# Check if date older than 60 days

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a date in this format: 2021-01-26

How would I check to see if this date is 60 days old?

Something like this?

```
if ($date -gt 60)
then

        echo "Date is older than 60 days"

fi
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you trying to archive?

Comment: Are you testing the modification date of some files?

Comment: I'm taking in a string of a specified date and am wanting to see if today's date is 60 days older.

Comment: I would like to do something like this:

if (($date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays > 60)
     matchFound = true;

Comment: Do you want to assign `$date` to a future date?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `date` command to create the date 60 days ago, and compare with that.

```
sixty_days_ago=$(date +%F -d '60 days ago')
if [[ $date < $sixty_days_ago ]]
then echo "Date is older than 60 days"
fi
```

Comment: version  for BSD `date -v-60d +%F`